# Is smartcard logon in windows bound to minidrivers and MS base CSP or any CSP will work?

Tags: windows, smartcard

As a developer, what I should give windows for smart card logon functionality?
Does only minidriver + existing base smartcard csp work
or if I develope a whole CSP I can have smartcard logon working?

Answer (score 0):

You should read [The Smart Card Cryptographic Service Provider Cookbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953432.aspx). Take a closer look at **Windows 2000 interactive logon** section. It has all the functions you need to implement in your CSP and the order in which these functions are called.